# Why am I getting this warning from log4j?

Tags: java, log4j

I just added the jar file downloaded to my external library. Do I need to do any configuration for apache.log4j library? What should I do to stop initialize the log4j system?

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (FaceRecognition).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Comment: Do you have `log4j.properties` in your `CLASSPATH`.

If yes then please post the contents here.

Comment: read the **** manual. :) And Google. This is very common issue. And Log4J manual is one of the best.

Comment: Did you `See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very Simple to add logging in Java See [here](http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/?p=237). You need to set proper log4j properties file and its initialization in log4j class. See my mentioned link.

Answer (score 0):

The log4j jar is not in the build path or log4j properties file is not in the build path. try to include the log4j jar in the build path it will work. i have pasted the log4j.jar in the web-inf/lib folder.